# Why is there a hat for Hanukkah but not for Christmas?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

I couldn't help but notice that there is a hat for a Jewish festivity:

> Sufganiyot:
> Post a question, answer, vote, or comment during Hanukkah (Dec 18-26)

but not a single one for the Christian festivities.
What was the motivation behind this?

Comment: For those (like me) who were wondering: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufganiyah

Comment: There's a legitimate question here and a good answer to it, but the comments have devolved into argument.  I've cleaned it up and I'm locking the comments for a few days to let everything cool down.

Answer (score 29):

The themes of the hats vary from year to year. For example, in [2016, we had many hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288271/323179) themed around religious holidays:

- "Bûche de Noël": Christmas

  - December 25th is Christmas Day. It's spelled out in the name of the hat: *[Noël](https://www.etymonline.com/word/noel)* comes from Latin *natalis*, meaning "birth", and is another word for Christmas. The hat itself is a [yule log](https://www.almanac.com/content/what-yule-log-christmas-traditions), which is a Christmastime tradition in itself. ("Cruse of Oil", the 2020 Chanukah hat, did not use the word "Chanukah" either.)
- "Epiphany": January 6th, not Christmas but very related
- "No Longer Grinchy": Alluding to The Grinch, a story about Christmas
- "I Have A Little Dreidel": Chanukah
- And even "Third Time's A Charm": Looks like St. Patrick's Day (again a Christian holiday)

In [2020](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357915/323179), we saw the return of "Bûche de Noël" and a different Chanukah hat.

As a note, some of the [goals this year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384857/323179) with the designs were to "Recognize a variety of cultures" and "Hit the memes and cultural references really hard".

It all balances out.

Comment: For a full list of holiday-related hat triggers, see the very last items on the ["common triggers" list on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304804/winter-bash-common-triggers).